# Dynamic right pane styling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like right submenu as pane. When clicking on 2 link in first div, 2 div has to show. When clicking 2nd ( or any element ) element from 2nd div 3rd div has to show 
I tried something like ( as of now all divs are `display:block` )

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        
        </style>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
        <style>
        .my_class {
             height:200px;
             width:100px;
             border:1px solid;
             float:left;
             position:absolute;
        }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="my_class">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="my_class">
                        <p><a href="#">Something2</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my_class">
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my_class">
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can somebody help me to correct alignment issue ?
Submenu actually goes 4 times to right. It should be aligned as one by one.

Comment: wrap it with another div and float it.....!

Comment: @Jai total width of all divs actually larger that than the parent div ( col-xs-2 )

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
 Change the class the class cl-xs-2 to cl-md-3. 
 and remove the `position:absolute; and left:100%;display` <- don't need that stuff.

**Note** I see your repeating styles a lot height, width etc.
You can just setta class to all those div's and have one **css** rule to set the properties for all the divs.

[Take a look at this](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/applyingcss/) I just found it, but it seems like a decent tutorial.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  </style>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div style="height:200px;width:100px;border:1px solid;float:left;">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <div style="height:200px;width:100px;border:1px solid;float:left;">
          <p><a href="#">Something2</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style="height:200px;width100px;border:1px solid;float:left;">
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style="height:200px;width100px;border:1px solid;float:left;">
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">Something2-1-1</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't increase width of parent div, Child elements has to overflow. Even though it should be displayed.